# Understanding fnServerData in Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to use Datatables in my project. I want to understand the use of "fnServerData" callback option. I have gone through the doc [Here](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnServerData) and have seen following example code -

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "xhr.php",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
      oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
        "dataType": 'json',
        "type": "POST",
        "url": sSource,
        "data": aoData,
        "success": fnCallback
      } );
    }
  } );
} );
```

What is "sSource", "aoData" parameters here and how we are supplying values in it? 
Also, instead of putting a JSP or PHP as a source (sAjaxSource), can we submit a form which will get JSON data dynamically?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`fnServerData` is an internal function in `dataTables` that can be overwritten with your own `ajax` handler. In this case with a comfortable `jQuery` function [Read more here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

The parameters are defined in `dataTables` core and are required in this particular order:

1 - `sSource` is the URL where your datasource is located. It is set at initialization to the value in `sAjaxSource`. In this case `xhr.php`

2 - `aoData` is an array of parameters that will be sent to the datasource. This contains by default `paginationinfo`, `sortinginfo`, `filterinfo` etc. (which are automatically set by the core) to which your `dataSource` script should react. (For Example: Limit an sql query to `pagesize` etc.) To send more info to your request you can push other values to `aoData`. Like so:

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
               aoData.push( { "name": "Input1", "value": $("#data1").val() } );
               aoData.push( { "name": "Input2", "value": $("#data2").val() } );
  oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
```

> (Will get the values of two input fields named data1 and data2 via jQuery from a
>   form and include them in the POST as Input1 and Input2)

If you want to know what's being sent, you can look at the POST Data with `Firebugs` console, or you can change type to `GET`. Then you'll see the passed parameters in the address bar (Beware that this can be a very long string which might get cut off).

3 - `fnCallback` is also a built-in function of the core that can be overwritten, but is not in this case. You should provide your own function in case you want to do some post-processing in `JS` after the data was received.

Regarding the second part of your question: Of course you don't need to use `PHP` or `JSP`. Any server-side language that can serve `JSON` data dynamically is fine (Python, Node, you name it ...)

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET MVC and your controller action has a parameter of type jQueryDataTableParamModel, take into account that you need to create a child class (a class that extends from jQueryDataTableParamModel) and add a property for each extra field that you send from the client to the server. In this case, you should add two properties: Input1 and Input2. That way, ASP.NET MVC will bind the values automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sadly I don't know a lot about ASP.NET MVC:-( But I'm sure this is helpful!

Comment: Great! solved my problem on sending column name instead column index for sorting.

Comment: Hello @mainguy, I checked the documentations of the actual Datatables version, but found no param "fnServerData". I found this in legacy documentation, but no alternative in current versions. Do you know how to do this in the latest versions? Could you please update your answer?