# How do I pass additional parameters to the jQuery DataTable ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

When loading a jQuery DataTable, I have the code shown below.  How do I pass additional parameters to the AJAX call?  The fnServerParams callback suggested in the questions and answers below does not work.  That is, naively using `aodata.push()` results in "push is undefined" (because, indeed, aodata is not an array).  So what's the correct way to do this?

**Related questions:**

- [Datatables serverside. Send extra parameters asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26824732/188474)
- [Understanding fnServerData in Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21704398/188474)

**Code:**

```
self.dataTable = self.dataTableContainer.DataTable({
            "autoWidth": false,
            "bSort": false,
            "displayStart": 0,
            "paging": false,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "dom": "<'dataTables_header dashboard_alert_history__alertHeader'i>",
            "ajax": {
                url: getDataUri,
                error: onError,
                cache: false,
                "fnDrawCallback": onTableDrawn,
            },
            "fnDrawCallback": onTableDrawn,
            "language": {
                "info": resources.alarmHistory,
                "infoEmpty": resources.alarmHistory,
                "infoFiltered": ''
            },
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": "timestamp",
                    "mRender": function (data) {
                        return IoTApp.Helpers.Dates.localizeDate(data, 'L LTS');
                    },
                    "name": "timestamp"
                },
                {
                    "data": "deviceId",
                    "mRender": function (data) {
                        return htmlEncode(data);
                    },
                    "name": "deviceId"
                },
                {
                    "data": "ruleOutput",
                    "mRender": function (data) {
                        return htmlEncode(data);
                    },
                    "name": "ruleOutput"
                },
                {
                    "data": "value",
                    "mRender": function (data) {
                        return htmlEncode(IoTApp.Helpers.Numbers.localizeFromInvariant(data));
                    },
                    "name": "value"
                },
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3],
                    "className": 'table_alertHistory_issueType',
                    "width": "20%"

                }
            ],
        });
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I neglected to RTFM.  The `fnServerParams` callback is now [legacy](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) for versions 1.9 and earlier.  In the latest version of DataTables, you leverage the ajax data parameter [as described in the DataTables documentation](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html).  In the example below, appending `mykey` to the `d` object will do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "scripts/server_processing.php",
            "data": function ( d ) {
                d.myKey = "myValue";
                // d.custom = $('#myInput').val();
                // etc
            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Awesome!  This is just what I'm looking for. Thanks for your good answer!

Comment: how to do this on a already initialised datatable ?

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal It's been many years for me, but I think that's a different question.  You're asking, "how do I manipulate the table after it is loaded?"  Or more likely, you want to catch the ajax promise and manipulate the data before it is displayed.

Comment: i wanted to pass extra paramaters to the ajax url after it is initialized. found out that i have to destroy the table and recreate it for that.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal I'm still looking for an answer for a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67376953/jquery-datatable-update-request-postdata-on-datatable-reload?noredirect=1#comment119092423_67376953.
Please help me if you have a solution.