# jQuery DataTables Ajax.Data dynamically populated with checkbox checked state not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables-1.10

I have a checkbox in my datatables table header that I'm trying to pass as a parameter for server side processing. It seems like this should be trivial, but I'm either overlooking something or I am missing something with how datatables works.

This is my input:

```
<input id="active-users-chk" type="checkbox" name="active-users-chk" checked="checked"> Active Users Only
```

This works outside of the datatables initialization:

```
$('#active-users-chk').on('change', function(){
    console.log($('#active-users-chk').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0);
    $('#mng-users-table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
});
```

but if I try to use it dynamically as an ajax.data parameter, it's always true:

```
"ajax": {
   "url": baseUrl + 'admin/get_users',
   "type": "POST",
   "data": {
     "active_only": $('#active-users-chk').is(':checked')
   }
},
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but can't seem to get this to work within the datatables initialization.

Comment: it works if i hard-code the value.

Comment: hmm also try adding `"serverSide": true,    ` option property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"ajax": {
              "url": baseUrl + 'admin/get_users',
              "type": "POST",
              "data": function(d) {
                d.active_only = $('#active-users-chk').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
              }
          },
```

[per this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33571906/4113027)

Comment: Great. It worked. I was able to send the updated state of my checkbox. Thanks.